# Search txt file for varying keyword - then assign to variable

Tags: python, file, search, keyword

I need to search a txt file for keywords in format "i-0xxxyyyzzzz" - where xyz are varying alphanumeric characters.
I would like to then assign each match assigned. Currently I can get as far as:

```
  f = open("file.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "i-0" in line:
        for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: print l,
        print
```

However this prints the whole line, and not just the keyword.

Comment: could you show us a sample input file and what you expect exactly?

Comment: @Kasramvd no, the current version would print 2 *lines*...

Comment: Essentially I'm searching a JSON file for randomly assigned server volume names. I want to then assign these "i-0..." format names to a variable so I can run tasks against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using regular expressions:

```
import re

token_regex = re.compile('i\-0[0-9a-z]*')
for line in open('file.txt'): // Note: 'r' is the default
   // You might find the token several times in the line
   matches = token_regex.findall(line)
   if matches:
     print '\n'.join(matches)
```

I'm not clear what you want to do with the matches. My example would print print them one per line. Also, could you have tokens that span two lines?

Comment: Single-line comments begin with the hash character # not // :)

Comment: There will only be one match per line, but multiple matches per file. Sample of the file - {
"Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "153_Peter", 
            "ReservationId": "r-TempDev", 
            "VolumeId": "i-0vol23_87bcf”,

Comment: Andrea - the code you suggest works like a charm. thanks. Would there be a way to say that the first match = a, then second match = b and so on? So I can call on these variables later.